# Confirm basic understanding of MongoDB's acknowledged write concern

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Using MongoDB (via PyMongo) in the default "acknowledged" write concern mode, is it the case that if I have a line that writes to the DB (e.g. a mapReduce that outputs a new collection) followed by a line that reads from the DB, the read will always see the changes from the write?

Further, is the above true for all stricter write concerns than "acknowledged," i.e. "journaled" and "replica acknowledged," but not true in the case of "unacknowledged"?

Comment: Map reduce is a bad example since it atomically writes the output collection

Comment: @Sammaye - yes, but does that (atomic) write by mapReduce always happen before the read happens, given "acknowledged" write concern? Is the situation different for update?

Comment: No, it depends, MongoDB has no idea that your read is waiting for that MR as such it will read what is there at the time you query, it will not wait for write concerned operations to complete,  unless it is single document, since transactions exist per document in MongoDB

Comment: @Sammaye - ok, in that case, given a write on line 1 and a read on line 2, how do I make sure line 2 see's line 1's write?

Comment: In the same script? If I remember right python is sync (unlike JS) as such it should work on acknowledged, sorry I didnt realise you were talking about a procedural script

Comment: @Sammaye - yep in the same (Python) script. Ok, so in this case the answer's to my questions are yes and yes? Just making sure, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, though unacknowledge does not truly exist anymore but yes, you have the right idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the write has been acknowledged, it should have been written to memory, thus any subsequent query should get the current data. This won't work if you have a replica set and allow reads from secondaries.

Journaled writes are written to the journal file on disk, which protects your data in case of power / hardware failures, etc. This shouldn't have an impact on consistency, which is covered as soon as the data is in memory.

Any replica configuration in the write concern will ensure that writes need to be acknowledged by the majority / all nodes in the replica set. This will only make a difference if you read from replicas or to protect your data against unreachable / dead servers.

Comment: Small clarification: a replica set configuration doesn't require writes to be acknowledged by a majority. That is only a requirement when the write concern `w` is set to a number bigger than half the number of replica set members, or `w=majority`. You can still do primary only acknowledged writes in a replica set with `w=1`, for example.

Comment: I can see where my confusion comes from. The MongdoDB doc on acknowledged write concern leads with: "With a receipt acknowledged write concern, the mongod confirms the receipt of the write operation." This implies the acknowledgement is just of receipt of the write; it does NOT imply that the client waits for success to continue. However, in the caption to an illustrative diagram, the docs say: "The client waits for acknowledgment of success or exception." That is much clearer -- and somewhat contradictory, i.e. the acknowledgement is of success/failure, not simply of "receipt" of the write.

Comment: N.B. The doc I'm referring to is here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-concern/#write-concern-acknowledged

Comment: @wdberkeley though only acking with primary does leave failover possibilties of losing that write in the event that failover occurs very quickly

Comment: If you have `w = 1, j = 0`, reads will see the write after the ack (also possibly before the ack for some documents), but the write could be lost before it is committed to disk. In `w = 1, j = 1`, once the write returns, the data is committed to disk and will persist if mongod shuts down unexpectedly. `j = 1` requires `w > 0`; `w = 0, j = 1` acts like `w = 1, j = 1`.

Comment: @wdberkeley though even the journal won't save you if the node is dead, only writing to redundant servers will help

Comment: Yes. Use replication for data redundancy. Journaling is for fast crash recovery.

Answer (score 4):

For example in case of WiredTiger database engine, there'll be a cache of pages inside memory that are periodically written and read from disk, depending on memory pressure. And, in case of MMAPV1 storage engine, there would be a memory mapped address space that would correspond to pages on the disk. Now, the secondary structure that's called a **journal**. And a journal is a log of every single thing that the database processes - notice that the journal is also in memory.

[image: MongoDB setup]

**When does the journal gets written to the disk?**

When the app request something to the `mongodb` server via a TCP connection - and the server is gonna process the request. And it's going to write it into the memory pages. But they may not write to the disk for quite a while, depending on the memory pressure. It's also going to update request into the journal. By default, in the `MongoDB` driver, when we make a database request, we wait for the response. Say an acknowledged insert/update. But we don't wait for the journal to be written to the disk. The value that represents - whether we're going to wait for this write to be acknowledged by the server is called **w**.

```
w = 1
j = false
```

And by default, it's set to **1**. **1** means, wait for this server to respond to the write. By default, **j** equals false, and j which stands for journal, represents whether or not we wait for this journal to be written to be written to the disk before we continue. So, what are the implications of these defaults? Well, the implications are that when we do an update/insert - we're really doing the operation in memory and not necessarily to the disk. This means, of course, it's very fast. And periodically (every few seconds) the journal gets written to the disk. It won't be long, but during this window of vulnerability when the data has been written into the server's memory into the pages, but the journal has not yet been persisted to the disk, if the server crashed, we could lose the data. We also have to realize that, as a programmer just because the write came back as good and it was written successfully to the memory. It may not ever persist to disk if the server subsequently crashes. And whether or not this is the problem depends on the application. For some applications, where there are lots of writes and logging small amount of data, we might find that it's very hard to even keep up with the data stream, if we wait for the journal to get written to the disk, because the disk is going to be 100 times, 1,000 times slower than memory for every single write. But for other applications, we may find that it's completely necessary for us to wait for this to be journaled and to know that it's been persisted to the disk before we continue. So, it's really upto us.

The **w** and **j** value together are called write concern. They can be set in the driver, at the collection level, database level or a client level.

[image: write concerns settings]

1 : wait for the write to be acknowledged
0 : do not wait for the write to be acknowledged
TRUE : sync to journal
FALSE : do not sync to journal

There are also other values for **w** as well that also have some significance. With `w=1` & `j=true` we could make sure that those writes have been persisted to disk. Now, if the writes have been written to the journal, then what happens is if the server crashes, then even though the pages may not be written back to disk yet, on recovery, the server can look at the journal on the disk - the `mongod` process and recreate all the writes that were not yet persisted to the pages. Because, they've been written to the journal. So, that's why this gives us a greater level of safety.